# How to remove class on mouseleave

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove the class on `<div id="track_order" class="active">` after `mouseleave` on`<div class="box_circle">`. How can I achieve this?

Here is my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cf9dY/

***jQuery***

```
jQuery('#b_track_order').click(function(){
    jQuery('#track_order').addClass('active');
});
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="order">
    <div class="rope"></div>
    <div id="track_order">
        <label>Order number</label>
        <input type="text" value="Order number">
        <label>Phone number</label>
        <input type="text" value="Phone number">
        <label>Address</label>
        <input type="text" value="Address">
    </div>
    <div class="box_circle">
        <div class="loop"></div>
        <div class="circle_order">
            <div class="pos">
                <div class="order"></div>
                <div class="follow">
                    <a class="button" href="#"><span>Order</span></a>
                    <a id="b_track_order" class="button" href="#"><span>Track Order</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tell us more about what you would like to achieve and what you have tried so far. Provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) if possible.

Comment: I`Like Add class After Click Button And Remove class unhover Box For animation with css3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly, you want to remove the added class on `mouseleave` event of the `box_circle`, just as you are using `addClass()`, you can simply use `removeClass()` method:

```
$('.box_circle').on('mouseleave', function() {
   $('#track_order').removeClass('active');
});
```

As you probably know, IDs are supposed to be unique, if you are using IDs just for selecting the elements, you can use classes and jQuery's `.prev()` and `closest()` methods instead:

```
$('.box_circle').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
}).find('a.track_order_btn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.box_circle').prev().addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at the examples in http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/ and http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/